# How can I ensure my monk is in range for her attacks?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I very recently (finally) killed The Butcher in *Diablo 3*. However, I ran into a slight problem during our battle.

About halfway into the fight, I noticed that a lot of my attacks weren't making contact. After paying a little bit more attention, I noticed that my fists simply were not reaching this massive demonic spawn. I was not holding shift, I was simply doing my best to get in close and land a few punches before fleeing from his devastating attacks.

**How can I ensure this doesn't happen again?** Growing longer arms seems out of the question.

Comment: Were you by a corner or some other object? I noticed your character will try and attack through corners or certain objects, however your attacks will not hit over these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually clicking on the enemy, instead of shift-clicking, should be enough to ensure that the attack will hit, unless you retreat too quickly; your problem seems to be that you have indeed retreated too quickly. You have to wait until the attack actually makes contact before retreating :)

### How to make sure the attack lands

I think a good option will be to enable damage numbers on enemies (via the gameplay options menu). That way when you land a hit you will see the damage number floating over your enemy, and when you don't - you won't.

If you prefer to avoid that, I think the best way will be to watch for the small things that accompany damage-dealing:

- Your character's animation reaches a certain phase
- You hear an attack-landing sound
- You see the monster turn white for an instant

I'm sure that with a little practice you'll get good in spotting these.

### Increasing your range

Other than that, you can work on switching to skills that will help you land hits from further away. These include:

- [Deadly Reach](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/deadly-reach), obviously, with any rune option
- [Fists of Thunder](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/fists-of-thunder) with Thunderclap
- [Crippling Wave](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/crippling-wave), especially with Tsunami
- [Way of the Hundred Fists](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/way-of-the-hundred-fists) with Fists of Fury
- And you can also start fights with [Dashing Strike](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/dashing-strike), which will instantly get you in melee range.

Answer (score 2):

Certain attack abilities on the monk have increased range, you could try using Deadly Reach, it has a longer melee distance than his other abilities.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found on my monk to make sure my attacks landed was to use the teleporting punch rune (can't remember name off the top of my head).  Every time I attack it sends me right to my target, making sure that I'm close enough to hit the enemy.  (This was also great for chasing down those damn treasure goblins...)